# IDA Pro finding functions that have different addresses in a new version of a binary?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, reverse-engineering, ida

With IDA Pro Decompiler,
i was looking for an way to trace the address of a function when the file changed.

For example, I have a `.so` (ELF) file and its version 1.0
there a function called
`[ Writer_Starting ]`
and This Function Address is
`[ 0x3DA224 ]`

well after a while , and after updating the .so (elf) file by his owner to 1.1
the function address changed to
`[ 0x3DA228 ]`

well , is there any way to automatically find all the changed address for functions
by comparing the old version of the same file ?

or a way to get specific address like example
i put the old address
`[ 0x3DA224 ]`
then i found the new one
`[ 0x3DA228 ]` ?

Comment: Have you considered something like `nm foo.so` on both binaries to dump symbol `address   name` records, and using `diff` on that text output?

Comment: Chances are that if one function moved 4 bytes, every other function higher in address moved as well.

Comment: Comparing different versions of the same binary is a common task and there are tools doing that, for example this https://github.com/joxeankoret/diaphora.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError actually i tried to keep on that path , but some functions moved with different bytes , as example 0x3BAFD30 it become 0x3BAFD34
so this address moved by 4 bytes
but other address like this one 0x070AAE1C
moved to be 0x070AAE28
so its moved more than 4 bytes

Comment: @nevilad well i will start looking for it right now thank you

Comment: @PeterCordes couldn't understand what you mean , can you explain more ?

Comment: `nm` from GNU binutils dumps symbols, with their addresses, one per line.  You can diff that output.  (But if most symbols have changed, the diff output won't be very useful, just a huge block of removed lines and another huge block of added lines.)  You're analyzing `.so` files so I assume you're on a system with normal Unix tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can create signatures of the functions in v1.0 with a tool like IDB2PAT, then match those signatures in v1.1 with FLIRT functionality of IDA. But the function body must remain completely unchanged for it to work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).